# Socket stuck on lug nut stuck on wheel

Tags: lug-nut

With the acknowledgement that this is not my finest hour, I've got an issue with a stuck and rounded off lug nut.

[image: Arrrgh]

(This is not my photo, but it shows my problem exactly)

Long story short, I need to get this off, preferably without damaging the stud (I don't care about the lug nut, it's obviously a lost cause)

Update: Wailed on it with a hammer all around the side and it fell right off!

Comment: Put some big vise grips on it and wiggle?

Comment: I'm not seeing an image ... ??

Comment: Your update was my suggestion! Oh and good luck getting the old nut off- carefull drilling is required or else you damage the wheel - as is evident ion one of mine and no it was not me - prior damage...

Comment: Getting the nut off was a bit of an ordeal - I've only got hand tools, so I made do with a nut remover, a tire iron, a five foot metal pipe, WD-40, and my boyfriend. Luckily, the only thing that took damage seems to be the nut, which was basically turned into shrapnel.

Comment: For the record: cast iron tools aren't well suited for loosening wheel screws. Get a forged wheel cross.

Comment: So you got the nut off? Post your solution as an answer please!